# Mule Read timed out exception

Tags: http, mule, outbound

I have an esb from which i make a webservice call,which works fine most of the times, but sometimes i get the below exception

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:129)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:218)
    + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
```

the weird thing is after i get this exception, some times the http outbound call still succeeds and some times does not succeed

why is this not consistent?

is there a chance that some configuration on mule http connector can help this exception scenario behave consistently?

All i am asking is... how to stop the http outbound request from getting processed after a read timed out exception is thrown?

the flow looks like below shown code

```
<queued-asynchronous-processing-strategy name="allow2Threads" maxThreads="2"/>

<flow name="TestFlow" processingStrategy="allow2Threads">
     <vm:inbound-endpoint path="performWebserviceLogic" exchange-pattern="one-way" />

    ....  some transformation logic
    ....
    <http:outbound-endpoint address="http://localhost:8080/firstwebservicecall" responseTimeout="65000" exchange-pattern="request-response"/>
    ....
    ....  some transformation logic on response...
    <http:outbound-endpoint address="http://localhost:8080/secondWeberviceCall" responseTimeout="20000" exchange-pattern="request-response"/>
    ......some transformation logic on response...

    <catch-exception-strategy>
        <choice>
            <when expression="#[groovy:message.getExceptionPayload().getRootException.getMessage().equals('Read timed out') and message.getSessionProperty('typeOfCall').equals('firstWeberviceCall')]">
                    .... unreliable ...result... as firstWeberviceCall may succeed even after the control comes here
                    and if we process http://localhost:8080/firstwebservicecall .. the transaction takes place twice... as already it succeeded above even after an exception is thrown
            </when>
            <when expression="#[groovy:message.getExceptionPayload().getRootException.getMessage().equals('Read timed out') and message.getSessionProperty('typeOfCall').equals('secondWeberviceCall')]">
                    ..... reliable ... if control comes here and if we process http://localhost:8080/secondWeberviceCall .. the transaction takes place only once
            </when>
            <when expression="#[groovy:message.getExceptionPayload().getRootException.getMessage().equals('Connect timed out') and message.getSessionProperty('typeOfCall').equals('firstWeberviceCall')]">
                ....reliable
            </when>
            <when expression="#[groovy:message.getExceptionPayload().getRootException.getMessage().equals('Connect timed out') and message.getSessionProperty('typeOfCall').equals('secondWeberviceCall')]">
                ....reliable
            </when>
        </choice>
    </catch-exception-strategy>   
</flow>
```

Comment: Can you share your flow configuration. It would be easier to grab your context.

Comment: Do you check the status code received after each `http:outbound-endpoint`?

Comment: i did not check it.. but i guess it should be 500 as it landed in catch block.. but the oubound call proves to be successful when i check the database.. so iam not processing firstwebservicecall again in catch block which solves the business logic ... but technically it is wrong i feel...

Comment: If I understood correctly, `readTimeOut` occurred for your `firstwebservicecall` and `secondWeberviceCall` got succeeded. Is it correct?

Answer (score 1):

You can configure, thus increase, the time-outs of the HTTP transport in different places:

- [Response time out on the endpoints](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/HTTP+Transport+Reference#HTTPTransportReference-ResponseTimeout),
- [Connection and socket timeouts on the connector](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/TCP+Transport+Reference#TCPTransportReference-Attributesof%3Cconnector...%3E).

This is just pushing the problem further though: increasing the time-outs may solve your issue temporarily but you're still exposed to the failure.

To handle it properly, I think you should strictly check the response status code after each HTTP outbound endpoint, using maybe a `filter` to break the flow if the status code is not what you expect.

Also, it's well possible that you get a response time out after the HTTP request has been received by the server and before the response gets back to Mule. In that case, as far as Mule is concerned, the call has failed and must be retried. Which means the remote service must be idempotent, i.e. the client should be able to safely retry any operation that failed (or it thinks has failed).

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply,
As suggested by you i checked the http status code and observed that it is some times 200 as soon as it entered catch-exception-strategy and some times null, but based on database result check, none of them prove to be consistent on the server request acceptance or not in case of socket time out exception

Comment: is there any way to check that server did or did not receive client request in case of this read timeout exception???

regarding idempotent implementation of server side(in my case its just another esb calling a webservice)..
are you suggesting to use
http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current/apidocs/org/mule/routing/IdempotentMessageFilter.html
if yes can you just give me an outline idea of this implementation 
Thanks

Comment: Not sure I follow you: are you saying that you can sometimes get 200 even if the exception is thrown?

Comment: Yes David, iam surprised to see Http status equal to 200 or null inside the catch exception strategy under load testing scenarios.. for ex:- if 5000 records were in vm queue and were entering the flow as shown above through vm:inbound , i get this read timed out exception for few records like 2 or 3 and out of those 2 or 3 , few will have http status 200 and others null inside catch block

Comment: i have <queued-asynchronous-processing-strategy name="allow2Threads" maxThreads="2"/> configured on my flow with 2 threads as shown above

Answer (score 1):

check server SO_TIMEOUT in httpconnection, set it to 0

check - https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-6331

Comment: Thanks!  To help others find the setting.  Edit connector configuration, go to the Timings tab, set Client SO_TIMEOUT and Server SO_TIMEOUT to 0.